# Python flask __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument, почему возникает ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-программирование, flask

Есть веб-приложение, в routes.py есть функция регистрации. Вроде все прописано правильно (в аналогичном коде все работает).
Возникает ошибка:

```py
user = User(email = form.email.data, fullName = form.fullName.data, phone = form.phone.data) TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fullName'
```

Не могу понять причину этой ошибки, гугление говорит что это может быть из-за ключевого слова `method`, но я заведомо использую `methods`.

```
routes.py:
@app.route('/registration', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    conn = connectDB.get_connection()
    curs = conn.cursor()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(email = form.email.data, fullName = form.fullName.data, phone = form.phone.data)
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        conn = connectDB.get_connection()
        curs = conn.cursor()
        sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, passhash, fullname, phone) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"
        curs.execute(sql, (user.email, user.passHash, user.fullName, user.phone))
        conn.commit()
        curs.close()
        conn.close()
        flash('Вы успешно зарегистрированны')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('registration.html', form = form)

users.py:
    class User(UserMixin):
        def __init__(self,id=None,email=None,passHash=None, fullName=None, phone=None):
            self.id = id
            self.email = email
            self.passHash = passHash
            self.fullName = fullName
            self.phone = phone
        def set_password(self, password):
            self.passHash = generate_password_hash(password)
        def check_password(self, password):
            return check_password_hash(self.passHash, password)
        def get_id(self):
            return self.id



class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    fullName = StringField('ФИО', validators = [DataRequired('Это обязательное поле'), Length(min = 8, max = 30, message = 'Длина должна быть между %(min)d и %(max)d символами')])
    email = StringField('Электронная почта', validators = [DataRequired('Это обязательное поле'), Email(message="Некорректный почтовый адрес"), Length(min = 8, max = 40, message = 'Длина должна быть между %(min)d и %(max)d символами')])
    password = PasswordField('Пароль', validators=[DataRequired(message="Это обязательное поле"), Length(min=6, max=32, message='Длина должна быть между %(min)d и %(max)d символами')])
    password2 = PasswordField('Повторите пароль', validators=[DataRequired(message="Это обязательное поле"), EqualTo('password', message='Пароли должны совпадать')])
    phone = StringField('Номер телефона', validators=[Length(min = 11, max = 12, message = 'Длина должна быть между %(min)d и %(max)d символами')])
    submit = SubmitField('Регистрация')
```

Comment: ошибку то приведите

Comment: @JopaBoga поправил текст вопроса

Comment: Либо не тот класс достали, либо у вас буква где-то не латинская затесалась

Comment: а вы импорт класса сделали?

Comment: @JopaBoga если вы про файл routes, то да: from app.user import User, load_user я там прописал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После проверки, оказалось что объявление класса происходило в том же файле что и должно, но на пару сотен версий раньше. Как это вышло - хз, в редакторе был открыт нужный файл. Открыть дыру в пространственно-временном континууме помогло "go to definition" из vs code, оно показало что обращается к версии класса в которой и правда еще нет никаких "fullname".